# MIUI в версиях Android 6 и выше , в фоне в foreground сервисе перестает работать запрос на определения местоположения

Tags: android

Возникла ситуация  связанная с такими прошивками как MIUI  в версиях Android 6 и выше ,  в  фоне в foreground сервисе  перестает работать  запрос на определения местоположения requestLocationUpdates,  в самом LocationCallback не вызываются методы  onLocationResult() и onLocationAvailability(), при это все настройки энергосбережения выключены для приложения. При разворачивании приложения определение местоположения корректно отрабатывает. Вопрос как заставить на прошивках MIUI в фоне брать последнее местоположение пользователя?

Comment: посмотрите может у приложения стоит жесткий контроль активности, и его система глушит через некоторое время

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете списке быть запрета на фоновую деятельность в самой прошивке и вам нужно поискать есть ли в ней менеджер, например у Samsung, Huawei, Xiaomi есть свои SecurityManager.